# C# EWS File Attachment Size

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We are trying to send an e-mail with an attachment, but we get a "forcibly closed connection" when the size of the message + attachment is more than 48Kb. While with the Outlook we don't have this problem.

What are we getting wrong?

Code below:

```
 ExchangeService service = new 
 ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(login, pass, domain);
 EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
 ...
 message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(fileName);
 message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely its a problem with the network path so i would check for proxy servers or anything else that is within the network path the can affect communications

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here > https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686407/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```